# How to disable the logging of parameter values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, configuration, logging

Is there a way to disable the logging of the parameter values used in a query, while still logging the actual query itself?

I'd like to set `log_min_duration_statement = 0` to use with pgBadger. I'm getting two lines per query like:

```
LOG: Select * from table where id = $1

DETAIL: parameters: $1 = 55
```

I'd really like to suppress the `DETAIL` lines because it's bloating my logs and saving sensitive information.

Is it possible to disable this from within Postgres?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set `log_error_verbosity = TERSE`

[The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-ERROR-VERBOSITY)

> Controls the amount of detail written in the server log for each
>   message that is logged. Valid values are `TERSE`, `DEFAULT`, and `VERBOSE`,
>   each adding more fields to displayed messages. **`TERSE` excludes the
>   logging of `DETAIL`, `HINT`, `QUERY`, and `CONTEXT` error information.**

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: Where to set this? Do I need to restart Postgres after?